# Using sapply instead of a for loop

Tags: r

Working on a project where we need to take the average of numbers in a matrix with those around it. For example, imagine a 3x3 matrix such as

```
[(1,2,3), 
 (4,5,6), 
 (7,8,9)].
```

Step 1 is to add padding around the matrix. Lets say we add 1 layer of padding thus getting a `5x5` matrix

```
[[0,0,0,0,0], 
 [0,1,2,3,0], 
 [0,4,5,6,0], 
 [0,7,8,9,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0]]. 

matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,4,5,6,0,0,7,8,9,0,0,0,0,0,0), nrow=5, ncol=5, byrow=T)
```

Then we average and filter getting the final `3x3` matrix. The first row/first column of this matrix should be `(1+2+4+5)/9 = 1.33`.

Right now my code works and looks like

```
for(row in (k+1):(nrow(pad.m) - k)){
for(col in (k+1):(ncol(pad.m) - k)) {
  y <- pad.m[seq(row-k, row+k), seq(col-k, col+k)]
  filter.m[row-k, col-k]<- mean(y)
}
```

where k is the number of layers of padding and pad.m is our matrix. Unfortunately my professor says that this is too unwieldy and prefers sapply over 2 for loops. I was wondering how I could subset and iterate through the matrix with sapply.

Comment: In general terms, `sapply(df, fun)` is the same as `for (i in seq_len(ncol(df))) {fun(df[,i])}`. Could you add a reproducible example? I'm still not 100% sure what this "filter" operation is doing

Comment: You might get better answers if you replace the extremely generic title with one more focused on the actual question of "How can I do this operation?". Does this kind of operation have a name? It seems like how you'd blur a bitmap image, but I can't think of what you'd call it. I bet you'd get better answers if you asked about that

Answer (score 0):

Use `tensorflow`.  You can use either a convolutional layer or a pooling layer.  Example:

```
library(tensorflow)

mymat <- matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,4,5,6,0,0,7,8,9,0,0,0,0,0,0), nrow=5, ncol=5, byrow=T) # Your padded matrix

matrix1 <- tf$constant( array(mymat, dim=c(1,nrow(mymat),ncol(mymat),1)), dtype="float64" )
pool1 <- tf$nn$avg_pool(matrix1, c(1L,2L,2L,1L), c(1L,1L,1L,1L), "SAME")
sess <- tf$Session()
sess$run(tf$global_variables_initializer())
res <- pool1$eval(session=sess)
sess$close()
```

The above takes the average over 2x2 regions.  But you added up the 2x2 regions and then divided by 9, which is weird, but okay.  So you can get the results like this:

```
res <- res[1,,,]
(res * 4/9)[-1,][,-1][-(3:4),][,-(3:4)]


         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 1.333333 1.777778
[2,] 2.666667 3.111111
```

The above is just formatting the array output back to matrix.

Comment: I think what they want to do is take the average of each 3x3 region

Comment: @divibisan Maybe, but that's not what they wrote in their post.  It would just require changing a parameter tho ;)